# Restrict EC2 permissions for an IAM user to use an AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am the root owner of an AWS account with a couple of private AMIs and volumes. I would like IAM users that are a part of my account to **not** have access to these, but still be able to create their own AMIs, snapshots and volumes. I could not figure out how to do this via the web interface. I would love some help to do so!

Comment: I think you can tag those resources you want marked as private, then create an IAM policy that _Deny_ any action on resources with that particular tag name and value. Attach this policy to the users you create.

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic approaches to doing this.

**Restrict the Allow**

To start with, users have *no permissions* to do anything. You then grant permissions for what they can do.

When you grant them permission to `RunInstances`, you can specify that they cannot use the AMI (via `NotResource`):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny running an instance",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-abcd1234"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Add a Deny**

Alternatively, you could *grant them permissions as you currently do* but then **Deny** them access to the AMI. A *Deny* always overrides an *Allow*:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny running an instance",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-abcd1234"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```